# NameError: name is not defined para vetor já inicializado, como arrumar?

Tags: python, variáveis, datetime, random, syntax-error

Estou fazendo um programa para calcular um certo tempo, com probabilidade de algo acontecer e dar errado, mas estou recebendo

> NameError: name 'tempo_ida' is not defined

**a variável h está definida como 0.**

e depois o erro ocorre nessa parte do código

```
tempo_ida[h] = (random.randrange(3600, 18000) / prob_capC )  # calcula-se
tempo_ida[h] = random.randrange(3600, 18000)
tempo = tempo_ida[h]
```

como arrumo isso?

Comment: Olá, tente dar uma olhada [aqui](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/people/mccann/errors-python#Four)

Comment: Quando vc faz `tempo_ida[h] = ...`, vc já está tentando acessar a variável `tempo_ida` na posição `[h]`, mas a variável provavelmente não foi definida antes. Por isso o erro de que a variável não foi definida.

Comment: então, eu já tinha colocado h = 0, antes desse tempo_ida[h] do post, no caso teria que colocar antes algo como tempo_ida = 0 também?

Answer (score 1):

Bom, o que a mensagem de erro deixa bem explícito é que sua variável `tempo_ida` não foi definida. Verifique se a definiu antes de tentar acessá-la.

Procure sempre ler e interpretar o que a própria mensagem te informa, antes de abrir uma pergunta aqui :)

Comment: obrigado, sou novo em python. mas a inicialização não se daria no próprio tempo_ida[h] = (random.randrange(3600, 18000) / prob_capC ) ?
ou eu teria que colocar tempo_ida = 0? pois a variavel h já está inicializada com 0 e mesmo assim tenho esse erro

Comment: não estou conseguindo resolver com as soluções anteriores do mesmo problema pois nenhum deles é sobre vetor

Comment: o problema é que você está tentando acessar a posição de um vetor que ainda não foi definido (pelo menos não no trecho de código exposto). Uma maneira mais fácil de manipular um array em Python é através do método append( ), dessa forma, vc não precisa percorrer um loop for para atribuição (o que provavelmente esteja fazendo).